# sql server outer join with multiple or conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, outer-join

Using Sql Server 2008 we have a query joining two tables Customer and Customer_Info the columns look like

Customer

```
   visit_date
   customer_seq_num
```

Customer_Info

```
   customer_seq_num
   customer_detail_number
   customer_value
```

the join for this query looks like

```
    Customer 
    left outer join Customer_Info 
        on Customer_Info.customer_seq_num = Customer.customer_seq_num 
        and Customer_Info.customer_detail_number = 31 
        and (
            (right(Customer_Info.customer_value,4)='8788' and month(visit_date)=2) or
            (right(Customer_Info.customer_value,4)='8808' and month(visit_date)=12)or
            (right(Customer_Info.customer_value,4)='8891' and month(visit_date)=9)
       )
```

the issue is that if i run the query as is i get 400 records. If i remove the first condition from the "and portion" meaning i comment out

```
--(right(Customer_Info.customer_value,4)='8788' and month(visit_date)=2) or
```

I get more results.... shouldn't the way the or's and the and are arranged cause it to return more or the same number of records for each of those statments? why would removing an or cause more records to return? It seems like sql server is doing soemthing odd with the nested logic

thanks for any help

Comment: You mean `less or the same number of records` right?

Comment: I agree with your expectation. Are you sure that the `400` is the total number of rows? Many programs show you only the first X rows of a query that would return more.

Comment: i don't think so. It consistently shows the same two numbers when i run with or without that condition. wouldn't i see the same number if what i am using (sql server managment studio) if it was just tuncating at some point

Comment: user2989408 , i actually did mean more. 
it should be pulling 
where x or... 
x+1 or....
 x+2

Comment: Not sure how you'd get more rows by removing that condition...this is a left join, there should be the same number of rows from this query as in the customer table (or more if you are getting multiple matches per line)...not less.  Try running select count(*) from customer, then count(*) from the query...are those the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "more results"?  How many rows do you get?  How many do you get if you remove all three conditions?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the LEFT JOIN in the SQL query. If it was an INNER JOIN your expectation would be correct. In the case of a LEFT JOIN (or RIGHT JOIN) the join conditions are applied first and then the join is done. So every predicate on the left table (even if it is an AND with multiple OR predicates) will actually reduce the number of rows that are used for the final left join. [[reference]](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/15/sql-server-interesting-observation-of-on-clause-on-left-join-how-on-clause-effects-resultset-in-left-join/).

Comment: so your saying that since the month criteria is being applied to the primary table not the outer joined table ... that is causing it to reduce rows. 
If i take out the condition the fact that it is an outer join allows those same records to now come in?

Comment: Hmmm, I may have jumped the gun. My answer has to do with where predicates are being applied: in the FROM clause or in the WHERE clause. This is clearly not the case in the example you show.

Comment: My guess is the OR statement filters the 1 : M relationships that are present in both tables. The Customer_Info has a number of rows pointing to the same Customer row. What I find strange is that the 1 : M already show up if you remove a single OR statement. Could you update your question and also show the SELECT clause you're using? And maybe you could post some of the records that appear when you remove the OR statement?